# Multiple Jquery DataTables don't work on same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have two HTML tables on my Page and I want to fill data using jquery dataTable. Problem is, it only loads/render data for the first table and doesn't work when I try to do the same for the second table.

**JQuery Code**: I have moved dataTable code into a method `LoadGrid` and call it for both tables:

```
$.ajax({
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        url: urlGetData,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (obj) {
            var object = jQuery.parseJSON(obj.data);
            LoadGrid("#tblActivitySummary", object.ActivitySummary, columnKeys, pageCount); //Create datatable for first table
            LoadGrid("tblPaymentSummary", object.PaymentSummary, columnKeys, pageCount); //Create datatable for Second table
            }
        });
```

Method for DataTable:

```
function LoadGrid(tableId, gridData, columnKeys, pageCount) {
        $(tableId).dataTable().fnClearTable();
        $(tableId).dataTable({
            "pageLength": pageCount,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            "bSort": true,
            data: gridData,
            columns: columnKeys
        });
    }
```

Why it doesn't render second table?

Comment: you forgot to add `#` id selector `#tblPaymentSummary`

Comment: @Beginner Oh dear! Head desk. Thanks, you were really quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the '#' in front of your second selector.

```
LoadGrid("#tblActivitySummary", object.ActivitySummary, columnKeys, pageCount); //Create datatable for first table
LoadGrid("#tblPaymentSummary", object.PaymentSummary, columnKeys, pageCount); //Create datatable for Second table
```